# Is it against the Apache Beam Programming Model to Invoke an API?

Tags: apache-beam

When using Apache Beam to enrich data, would it be wrong to make an API call for each data item

(I'm new to Apache Beam)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can batch API calls for better performance. Check out "Batched RPC" example in [this](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) blog post.

Another thing to note is that beam cannot guarantee exactly-once for external API calls. If the pipeline in question needs exactly-once QoS, you  should strive to make API calls idempotent.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on Batch RPC.

Comment: What the difference between the class used by this blog post and the `batchElements()` transform?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the type of API call and the size of your data. If the data specify the API call that needs to be made, this is appropriate. However, if you have some limited set of data that is used to enrich your input elements, it may be possible to use parts of the Beam programming model to reduce the number of external calls required.

As an example, if the data that produces the results of your API call can be preloaded, you may be able to use a side input by reading all of the data and using `View.asMap` (or whatever view is appropriate), reducing the time number of API calls to some relatively constant number per execution. The side input can then be consumed by using `ParDo.withSideInputs`; see the [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/), specifically about [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-pardo) and [SideInputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-sideio)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply Thomas. May I also ask if it is an anti-pattern to make such an API call according the Apache Beam programming model?

Comment: It's highly dependent on your data and the external API; how appropriate it is is dependent on access patterns, availability of the external service, and other contextual elements. It may be inappropriate in certain contexts, but I wouldn't call it an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thank you Thomas!